# How to get the shortest token from a CSV variable in batch?

Tags: batch-file

Here's my code:

```
set csv="Desk,House,Car,Animal,Existentialism"
for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ("%csv%") do (
    set token=%~1
    echo "%token%"
)
```

This does not work. It only prints an empty string.

However, I need to find out the shortest token. How can I do that?

Comment: don't know how to do it in batch, but not too difficult to do in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the strings and make comparisons between them in a loop saving the smallest in length using just bat, try this code:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_cnt=999" & for %%i in =;(Desk,House,Car,Animal,Existentialism,
     )do set "_x=" & call %:^) "%%~i" & if !_x! leq !_cnt! =;(
          set "_str=%%~i" && set /a "_cnt=!_x!" );=
%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" =;( for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%G in =;(
   '"cmd.exe /u /c echo=%~1|find/v """')do set /a "_x+=1+0"
    exit /b);= else =;(echo\String !_str! length !_cnt! & endlocal);=
```

Comment: Man, this is very very complicated. Officially, this is a gibberish.

Comment: This do the job using only bat code d;)

Comment: Let me know if you want an explanation of the code runs...

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thank you. But I understand none of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in batch, but its easy in powershell in case you can use that too.

```
$words = @("Apple","Car", "Houses")
$shortest = ($words|sort -Property length)|select -first 1

write-host "The shortest word is: $shortest"
```